# iPhone - What is the correct way to implement the UIScrollView?

Tags: iphone, controller, scrollview

I have two UIViewControllers each with their own nib files. Each controller serves a different purpose. The idea was to add a UIScrollController and add both UIViewControllers to it so the user can easily scroll between them both.

Q1) Is this even possible? Or have I got the whole purpose of UIScollControllers incorrect, if so, what is the best alternative.

I have been poking around the internet and the best I can come up with is this:

```
ScoreViewController *scoreController = [[ScoreViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ScoreViewController" bundle:nil];
scoreController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 960f, 640f);
[self.scrollview addSubview:scoreController.view];
[scoreController release];

SettingsViewController *settingsController = [[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsViewController" bundle:nil];
settingsController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 960f, 640f);
[self.scrollview addSubview:settingsController.view];
[settingsController release];
```

This code is entered inside my RootViewController class. It doesn't seem to work though as I can't scroll between the two UIViewControllers I have added (score and settings). All what is displayed on the screen is the second controller added - the SettingsViewController.

Q2) Why is this broken?

Thank you. :)

Comment: If you receive an answer that solves your problem, you can show your appreciation by [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: Thanks - I tried las night but didn't know how to do so :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you place the first controller correctly, then you put the second above it.

```
settingsController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 960f, 640f);
```

1. 960x640 - this is not the correct way to enter coordinates (320x480 is the actual size) double size is used only for image files
2. 0.0f, 0.0f means x: 0, y: 0, so in the second controller you need x: 320, y: 0

then, you have to set the contentSize of the scrollView

```
scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320*2, 480);
```

Then enable the paging of the scrollView;

```
scrollview.pagingEnabled = YES;
```

And that should work :)